# Starting AnimationDrawable in ListView items. When are the items attached?

Tags: android, animation, android-listview

So I've been doing some reading for the past few hours and I understand that calling start() on an AnimationDrawable before the Drawable/ImageView is fully attached will not start the animation. This seems pretty consistent with the usual UI initialization process (like view's dimensions being returned as 0 right after adding the view).

I imagine that this same issue is at fault when I try to start the animation from the getView() method of an Adapter. Using a delayed Runnable that performs the start() call solves this problem but is clearly not a desirable solution.

Is there any way to receive a callback once ListView's items are "fully attached"?

Comment: Have you tried overriding [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow())?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html), you must wait until the `View` is attached to the window before starting animation. Therefor, you should add an `OnAttachStateChangeListener` to the view that will execute when it has been attached, and start the animation from there.

```
ImageView loadingImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
loadingImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progressdialog);
loadingImg.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
    AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
    loadingAnimation.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
  }
});
```

I've tried starting the animation in a `Runnable` in the `View`'s `post()` method, and that didn't work. The above method is the only way I've reliably been to have animation start in a `ListView`.